# How to get the ids of many to many relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models, `Foo` and `Bar`:
​​​​​

```
class Foo extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'foos';
    protected $fillable = array('name');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function bars() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('bar','foos_bars');
    }
}
```

```
class Bar extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'bars';
    protected $fillable = array('name');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function foos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('foo','foos_bars');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the `Foo` models and their related `bars` like this and then output it in json:

```
class FooController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $foos = Foo:with('bars')->get();

       return Response::json(array(
          'foos' => $foos->toArray()
       ),200);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the output. This will output something like this:

```
{
   "foos": [
      {
         "id": 1, 
         "name": "Foo 1", 
         "bars": [
            {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Bar 1",
               "pivot": {
                  "foo_id": 1,
                  "bar_id": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "Bar 2",
               "pivot": {
                  "foo_id": 1,
                  "bar_id": 2
               }
            },
            {
               "id": 3,
               "name": "Bar 3",
               "pivot": {
                  "foo_id": 1,
                  "bar_id": 3
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But all I really want is:

```
{
   "foos": 
        [{
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Foo 1", 
            "bars": [1, 2, 3]
        }]
}
```

Right now, I've been iterating over `$foos` like this to get the right code:

```
foreach($foos as &$foo) {

    $bar_ids = array();

    foreach($foo->bars as $bar) {
        $bar_ids[] = $bar->pivot->bar_id;                    
    }

    unset($foo->bars);
    $foo->bars = $bar_ids;                
}
```

But this seems to complicated and adds a lot of complexity I'm trying to get rid of. Is there a simpler way to get the desired output?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transformers/presenters for such thing, fractal is one you could consider. However, you can do pretty much the same easily with Eloquent:

```
// Foo
protected $hidden  = ['bars']; // don't show the collection in json
protected $appends = ['barsIds']; // but show additional info you need via accessor

public function getBarsIdsAttribute()
{
   return $this->bars->lists('id');
}
```

Now you can use the accessor directly:

```
$foo->barsIds; // [1,5,10]
```

and it is automaticly appended to the `toArray/toJson` output:

```
{
   "foos": [
      {
         "id": 1, 
         "name": "Foo 1", 
         "barsIds": [1,5,10]
      }
   ]
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT** When you want to output collection of `foos`, then remember to **eager load** `bars` relation, otherwise you will experience N+1 query issue.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Does this load eager loading though?

Comment: You eager load `bars` relation as usually.

Comment: This is so neat and simple! I've not used 'appends' before (documentation at the end of http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [lists](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_lists) method.

```
$foo->bars->lists('id');
```

Will give you an array of foo's bar ids.

Available on:

- Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::lists
- Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists
- Illuminate\Support\Collection::lists

#### some additional advice:

To return the data in the format you want, it might be nice to use transformers, like from the [fractal package](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) (or make a simpler version on your own, depending on your requirements).

The idea is to have something in the middle to format your data instead of dumping your models to a response in your controllers. It could directly take care of your issue and have added benefits like casting properties to types (like boolean and integers) as well as insulating your controllers from database changes.

A transformer could look something like this:

```
class FooTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * Transform this item object into a generic array.
     *
     * @param Foo $foo
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(Foo $foo)
    {
        return [
            'id'   => (int) $foo->id,
            'name' => $foo->name,
            'bars' => $foo->bars->lists('id'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into Fractal, might be a good idea cause this API is getting rather complex.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a GROUP CONCAT in the foo query, for which you'd need to use DB::raw().

There's also the lists() method, e.g.

```
public function barsIds() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('bar','foos_bars')
        ->lists('id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though, that causes an error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why that would be. I did test this first in a relational model pair of mine and it worked... Perhaps the result of the belongs needs to be checked before calling list(), but I don't normally do that.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 that may be because you are trying something like `Foo::with('barsIds')`

Comment: I am calling it like $bIds = Foo::find($fId)->barsIds();

Comment: @fungku you're right. when I remove 'bars' from `with`, it works, but I loose eager loading which is no bueno.

Comment: Don't execute the query in a relation, b/c you lose most of eloquent relation features.